# Edit Comment vai modal dialog box doesn't work correctly

Tags: cakephp

```
   <?php 
           echo $this->Form->postLink(
           '',
           array('action' => 'edit',$comment['id'],
               'controller'=>'Comments',

           ),array('class'=>'glyphicon glyphicon-edit','onClick'=>'showDialog()') )?>
```

> This is comment edit icon that I create when I click the Icon the
>   model dialog box is pop up .

```
 <div id="overlay" onClick="hideDialog()"></div>
 <div id="dialog">
 <h2>Edit Comment <span onClick="hideDialog()">&times;</span></h2>

   <?php echo $this->Form->create('Comment',array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'));?>
 <?php echo $this->Form->input('Comment.comment',array('class'=>'form-control'));
  echo $this->Form->end('Save');
  ?>

 </div>
 <script>
 function showDialog() {
 document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
 document.getElementById("dialog").style.display = "block";
 }
 function hideDialog() {
 document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById("dialog").style.display = "none";
 }
 </script>
```

> The dialog to edit the comment but The comment just add as a another
>   comment but not edit . Why? Here is the Edit Function in my controller

```
public function edit($id = null) {
        $user_id=$this->Auth->user('id');
        $comment_fields=$this->Comment->findById($id);
        $comment_id=$comment_fields['Comment']['id'];
        $comment = $this->Comment->findById($id);
        if (!($user_id == $comment_fields['Comment']['user_id'])) {
            $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to edit your post.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action'=>'../posts/view',$comment_fields['Comment']['foreign_id']));
        }

        if (!$comment) 
        {

            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'../posts/view',$comment_fields['Comment']['foreign_id']));
        }
        if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {

            if($this->Comment->id = $id)
            {
                if ($this->Comment->save($this->request->data)) {
                    $this->Flash->success(__('Your Comment has been updated.'));
                    $this->redirect(array('action'=>'../posts/view',$comment_fields['Comment']['foreign_id']));
                }
            }else{
                $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to update your Comment.'));
            }


        }
        if (!$this->request->data) {
            $this->request->data = $comment;
        }
    }
```

Comment: try with `$this->request->data['array_index']['id'] = $id` while updating

Comment: The Problem is when I use onclick method in my post link the edit function in my controller doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

> You are trying to assign a value in the if's conditional statement part!

`if($this->Comment->id = $id)` : This is wrong because that part is for checking conditions.

The solution to your problem would be:

```
$this->Comment->id = $id;
if ($this->Comment->exists()) {
    if ($this->Comment->save($this->request->data)) {
        $this->Flash->success(__('Your Comment has been updated.'));
        $this>redirect(array('action'=>'../posts/view',$comment_fields['Comment']['foreign_id']));
    }
}
else {
    $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to update your Comment.'));
}
```

Comment: But when I used edit ctp for the edit page the function work instantly . i just want my comment edit via my modal dialog box.but the edit postlink doesn't work for edit function .I think so

Comment: Then you should use action in your modal's form like so : `<?php echo $this->Form->create('Comment',array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data', 'action'=>'....'));?>`